# Input boxes in while loop

Tags: forms, input, while-loop

I am wondering how I can differentiate the name on the input box in a while loop so when I post I get 2 separate values. Here is my code:

```
   <form method="post" action="rewarded.php">
        <?php
        $nameqry="SELECT name FROM kids";
        $names=mysqli_query($conn, $nameqry) or die ("Error could not execute name query: " . mysqli_error());

        echo "<table>";
        while($namerow=mysqli_fetch_array($names)) {
        $name=$namerow["name"];
        echo "<tr><td>$name will use <input type='text' name='points'> points.</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<input type='submit' value='Submit'>";
        ?>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($namerow=mysqli_fetch_array($names)) {
        $name=$namerow["name"];
        echo "<tr><td>$name will use <input type='text' name='points-<?php echo $name; ?>'> points.</td></tr>";
        }
```

each time the code repeated in loop it gives you a different input name.

also you can use `name="points[]"`

it will return all names in a array

Comment: Awesome, I got this answer to work. Although I had to change it to name='points-$name'

rather than
name='points-<?php echo $name; ?>'

php tags were already open

Thanks!! :)

Comment: if this answer is working hit it up and accept it :)

Comment: I don't have enough rep to hit it up yet! how can I accept it?
I am very new to SO

Comment: Thanks mate :) Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could make the name a variable and change the variable on each loop.

```
$input_name_count = 1;

while($namerow=mysqli_fetch_array($names)) {
    $name=$namerow["name"];
    echo "<tr><td>$name will use <input type='text' name='".$input_name_count."'> points.</td></tr>";
    }
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use numbers (i.e. points1, points2, etc.or 1,2,3 etc.) make a list of names that you want.

```
$names_list = ['name', 'name 2', 'hippos'];
```

Then simply select the item you want from the list using a counter.

```
$counter = 0;

while($namerow=mysqli_fetch_array($names)) {
    $name=$namerow["name"];
    echo "<tr><td>$name will use <input type='text' name='".$names_list[$counter]."'> points.</td></tr>";
    $counter++;
    }
```

Comment: Cool!

So for you first example..
I could fetch post data like this:

$value1 = $_POST['input_name_count1']

?

Comment: $input_name_count is just a variable. When it is put into the name field, its name is not evaluated, only its value. so using the code above, the first field's name will be "1", the second would be just "2". If you wanted to put some text in front of that just add:  name='whatever".$input_name_count."'... This would make names "whatever1", "whatever2", etc.